# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I wrote a simple SQL query in Oracle which inserts some values.

But I got `SQLSyntaxErrorException` stating a "missing expression" error.

This my query:

```
String addManager = "INSERT INTO property_manager(EIN,NAME,HOME_PHONENUMBER,MOBILE_PHONENUMBER,EMAIL,PROPERTY_CIN)" +
       "VALUES (" + mein.getText() + ","  + mname.getText() +","+    mHome_phonenumber.getText() +","+ MMobile_phonenumber.getText()+"," + memail.getText() + ","+mproperty_cin.getText()+")";
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is using a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

- It prevents SQL injection
- Escapes invalid characters in your Strings (such as `'`) and the characters which will break your query
- handles null and empty Strings
- Uses Oracle's query parsing cache (for better performance)
- Handles types such as Date and Blob much easier

Just google for `java PreparedStatemnt` and you see lots of samples.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your values inside quotes.

```
String addManager = "INSERT INTO property_manager(EIN,NAME,HOME_PHONENUMBER,MOBILE_PHONENUMBER,EMAIL,PROPERTY_CIN)" +
   "VALUES ('" + mein.getText() + "','"  + mname.getText() +"','"+    mHome_phonenumber.getText() +"','"+ MMobile_phonenumber.getText()+"','" + memail.getText() + "','"+mproperty_cin.getText()+"')";
```

Or better yet, use parameters. Otherwise you risk sql injection attack.

Comment: how to put my values inside quotes can u write for me? thanks